# Prove that if a complex number raised to nth power equals one, then product of the solutions to this euqations is one

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I've thought of this "proof", but it seems lame to me (I'm not sure it is even a proof), I probably should have used other properties of complex numbers to write one.

So,

$z^n=1 \implies \sqrt[n]{z}=\sqrt[n]{1} \implies \sqrt[n]{1}_1 \times \sqrt[n]{1}_2 \times ... \times \sqrt[n]{1}_n = (\sqrt[n]{1})^n = 1$

And we know there are $n$ terms in the product because it is given by the fundamental theorem of algebra (which says that a polynomial of power $n$ has $n$ solutions). And the next step is given by the fact that the product of powers of $x$ is $x$ raised to the power of the sum of the powers of the factors.

This is obviously a homework, so, please don't assume much when replying! :)

Comment: what is $1$ in this case?

Comment: @Chinny84 Actually, the text of the assignment doesn't say, but I believe it is a real number.

Comment: @PeterFranek no? $(1 + 2)/2 = 3/2$... I eventually get to this formula, but I don't see how I could use it :(

Comment: It is $1$ or $-1$. Already for $n=2$, you get $1\times (-1)=-1$. Hint: what can you tell about $\frac{1}{n}(1+2+\ldots +n)$?

Comment: @PeterFranek oh... are you referring to the fact that $(-(n-1))+(-(n-2))+...+(-1)+0+1+2+...+(n-2)+(n-1)+n = n$ and then $n/n = 1$? Wouldn't I need to also somehow prove for odd and even cases, and I'm not sure whether the same theorem says anything about the number of positive and negative roots (or does it?).

Comment: @PeterFranek you are right, it could be $-1$, but I've just re-read the assignment, and that's what it asks me to prove. I guess then it must be a typo in the assignment!

Comment: The $n$th roots of $1$ are $e^{2i\pi r \over n}$ for $r = 0, 1 \ldots n - 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No proof is possible. The conjecture is false.

Suppose $a_i$, $i = 1, ..., n$ are the solutions to $z^n - 1 = 0$. Then

$$z^n - 1 = (z - a_1)(z - a_2)...(z-a_n)$$

When you multiply out the brackets, you get a polynomial in $z$ with constant term $$(-1)^n a_1 ... a_n$$

So, by equating coefficients, we have

$$a_1 ... a_n = (-1)^{n+1}$$

---

Possibly, the question is asking for the product of the *non-real* solutions to this equation.

- If $n$ is odd, the only real solution is $1$, so the product of
  the non-real solutions is $(-1)^{n+1} = 1$
- If $n$ is even, $+1$ and $-1$ are both solutions, so the
  product of the non-real solutions is $(-1)^{n+1} / (-1) = 1$ again.

Comment: Nope, this is actually a bogus assignment (it doesn't say that the roots should be non-real). I will have to ask the prof. to clarify it. But thank you for explanation!